# Why has Bill D. been hit with a 1 year suspension?

Tags: discussion, specific-user

I have been watching closely the events unfolding on Meta this past year or so which include the MK issue and more recently the deleting/locking of contest/take home questions. Now just a few minutes ago I logged into Bill D. account and it says that it has been temporarily suspended to allow it to "cool down". What does this mean? Furthermore I take it that some have considered his behaviour to be out of line, but does this mean we have to hit such an important contributor to our site with a 1 year suspension period?

Even though he changed his username to "Gone" and went into self - imposed exile just earlier today before the suspension I could see him on chat; in fact he told me of a suspension that he and another user were apparently hit with.

Comment: Suspensions are private, moderators are not allowed to reveal the details, so you likely won't get any detailed answers from moderators here. The suspended user is of course free to tell his side of the story via other channels, if he wants to do so.

Comment: Who can suspend a moderator: [*Quis custodiet ipsos custodes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F) ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Bill wasn't a moderator by that time. He wasn't even Bill anymore. He was "Gone".

Comment: @Asaf. I don't get the chronology: why and since when has Bill become "Gone"?

Comment: @Asaf I think Qia suspended Bill during their edit battle, so it might be possible to simply suspend mods.

Comment: Any moderator can suspend another moderator, but it just doesn't do anything. A suspended moderator can still perform any actions he could do before, and also can just unsuspend himself.

Comment: @Michael. So is it like in the cowboy films we all love: the first gunslinger who suspends the other wins?

Comment: @Georges: Two days ago Bill and Qiaochu got into a lock-unlock war of a question. This ended up when both were taken off the moderator team (at least temporarily, I suppose). Bill changed his username to Gone and claimed that he has given up on this site and whatnot. Last night Bill got suspended (after leaving the site), as his account will show - the suspension occurred on the 13th.

Comment: So Bill had to be removed as a mod first before the suspension to ensure he couldn't unsuspend himself. Who decided to remove Bill as a mod?

Comment: @Ragib: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/do-mods-of-stackexchange-sites-get-paid#comment24367_6799

Comment: @MadScientist I think it's only democratic that the community knows the reason behind Bill's suspension. Otherwise why was he chosen to be suspended and not the other parties involved?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree with your stand that we should know why he is no longer a moderator. I do not mean to side with Bill (or anyone) but from what I understand the issues of the past few days involved several parties. I would like to know why a particular person was chosen to be suspended and not say him/her as well as other people.

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose of the word "democratic" in your previous comment, except perhaps for demagogy.

Comment: @BenjaLim You'll have to take that up with SE, they decided that suspensions should be private. The general idea behind that is to avoid publicly shaming users for their mistakes or misbehaviour. Of course this is not all that effective in such highly-visible cases as this one. And to challenge the suspension, the suspended user can always appeal to the SE team directly.

Comment: I'm quite sure the reason he is no longer a moderator has to do with [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23681/194588) (read comments and edit history). Afterwards, he was supended as normal users for different reasons.

Comment: Apart from the reasons Mad Scientists enumerates two comments above this one, usually we cannot make public the reasons for suspensions because they involve information that is private (IPs, emails, various other things that only mods can access, &c)

Comment: @Michael: Is that really the thread you wanted to link to? It's an old meta.SO discussion of suspensions; I was expecting a more recent thread in which Bill participated.

Comment: @joriki My bad. It was [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256816/if-n-the-order-of-a-group-and-gcdk-n-1-then-there-exists-an-element-in) thread.

Comment: Voted to close, because the announcement post makes this question obsolete. The reasons were all over the map, so I picked the one that seemed least likely to offend, though none of the reasons are really right.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was re-opened. It was said that Bill was suspended for a year because it was his third suspension; and in the official announcement it was said that Bill was suspended for one reason or another. What possible reason is there for this thread to be reopened?

Comment: @AsafKaragila True. But just because the question has an accepted answer, is no reason to close the thread.

Comment: @Marvis: Where in my comment I wrote anything about an accepted answer? ;)

Comment: @AsafKaragila "It was said that Bill was suspended for a year because it was his third suspension" I thought this referred to Noah Snyder's/Michael Greinecker's answer. Also, if people prefer to close this thread, this should be closed as duplicate of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6837/announcement-a-note-on-recent-events?lq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we do anything to avoid losing Bill D?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/can-we-do-anything-to-avoid-losing-bill-d)

Comment: Voting to close: This has been answered in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/can-we-do-anything-to-avoid-losing-bill-d#comment13216_3531). I also think that you have been manipulated by BD [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/36?m=7265501#7265501) to ask this question. Perhaps [toxic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6839/) is phrasing it strongly, I cannot judge since I didn't have much to do with BD, but I certainly think that if one wants to discuss an issue on meta one should do so in person and not "delegate" others to do so.

Comment: He's gone again!

Comment: In the same vein, I wonder why high rep users as DonAntonio or AmWhy were suspended. Also, I have fond memories of Menni who also dissapered.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Obviously I don't have any official knowledge, but I happened to be watching around when this happened and Bill and another user were both suspended at the same time after they had a particularly acrimonious and impolite long exchange in comments. The suspensions were different lengths because one was a first suspension and one was a third suspension as explained in Michael's answer.

Comment: Very astute observation.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a cloud of mystery around deleted/suspended users. I must have seen at least 10 question about this guy!

Answer (score 10):

There is a standard protocol for suspension times. They get progressively longer. After a user has been suspended for 30 days, the next suspension is commonly for a year (the [official guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23681/194588) seem to be 120+ days). Here is information moderator Zev Chonoles [provided](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/can-we-do-anything-to-avoid-losing-bill-d#comment13216_3531) on January 24, 2012 on BD:

> **Feb 11, 2011:** Official warning given. Requested that (i) the user
>   be more civil (ii) the user does not bring up past interactions with
>   other users on other fora (iii) the user not to delete answers to shed
>   downvotes. Further violation will result in suspension. **Feb 28,
>   2011:** User suspended for 2 days for spiteful downvoting together
>   with a previous history of troublesome behavior. **Jan 23, 2012:**
>   User suspended for 30 days for being abusive to others.

The background of the first suspension can be seen [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/downvoted-by-another-user-for-the-wrong-reasons).

Comment: So now that Bill and Qiaochu are no longer moderators do we have another moderator (by) election?

Comment: @BenjaLim: This is a whole other question for a whole other thread. I would wait until the moderators finish whatever they are discussing about in the comment I left on your main question (a link to mixedmath comment). Then we can decide about that. Either way there are still six moderators, and it seems reasonable that they could hold up for a while if there are no troubles brewing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes that seems reasonable. When the relevant time comes I may ask a question on math.se/email the se team to ask if there will be an election.

Comment: @BenjaLim: I am fairly certain that this is something the moderators will take into account, so it seems reasonable that they will already announce what will happen with regards to that. In either case I think that the best thing to do would be to let things stay as they are for a few weeks, see if the smaller team works out for the site. Then see about elections.

Answer (score 5):

I am sure that the suspensions comply with all the rules. I would like to say that - in spite of their difference of opinion - both Bill and Qiaochu have contributed a huge amount to the site. The community can ill afford to have either of them "gone", particularly with the increased volume of questions - for both have regularly given answers which encompass mathematical precision and pedagogical sensitivity.

Comment: Bill decided that he is leaving on his own accord, before the suspension was "hit".

Comment: I also think that the same can be said on Arturo and t.b. and Zev. All of them left as well (with notably less drama, by the way).

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Maybe I wasn't watching as closely - and I hadn't realised. But you are right - especially considering the quality of contributions made - and the rate of attrition is a real cause for concern. There was a falling out on another site I'm involved with (not maths) over moderation - a couple of people left. It got personal for the moderators, but for the rest of us it was a mystery. Fortunately there was an end to it. I hope that this all settles down.

Comment: @Asaf: t.b. hasn't left (though he did reduce his participation, regrettably).

Comment: @joriki: His main account has been inactive and the profile says "gone.", his recent appearance was probably due to a mail notification on the truly interesting AC question.

Comment: @Mark: Yes. Bill and Arturo have both quite a long history of incompatibility (or so it seems). When Bill became a moderator it is likely that Arturo was more and more irritable of that fact. Some ugly comments thread on meta included a really shameful comment by Bill towards Arturo (it is now deleted, so you need 2577 points before you can see it). Whether or not that was the reason, it surely didn't help. Arturo was gone a day later. So now you apparently need to ask yourself, would you like Bill to return, or Arturo? Would you like person A or person B? Whose contribution is greater?

Comment: [cont] I don't think that this can be answered, and certainly no one should answer this in public anyway. Let me just finish by saying that I am sorry to see Bill going, but just as the site didn't collapse when Arturo left (and that guy was half the activity around!) I am certain that the site will do just fine without Bill.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Can you send me the link to the page where Bill made this comment towards Arturo? Also, was there any page where he did something similar to T.B.?  Thanks.

Comment: @Eric: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi#comment18574_4764 (There might be other deleted comments on the page related to that, but this whole thread is the one I am referring to.)

Comment: I would just like to add that I try to be a positive contributor to all discussions. I can only imagine that the down-vote on my answer reflects a level of information with which I have not engaged. I know I am sometimes crass. But the two people I named have educated me (and I am sure others). I posted another question about the qualities required of moderators - as participants, these two set a high threshold - and I want to acknowledge THAT.

Comment: @Asaf You see deleted comments after 10K?

Comment: @Eric: My extended absence from the site is completely unrelated to any of Bill's actions.

Comment: @t.b.: At no point I was suggesting that. I merely suggested that you were gone, and no one cried over several threads in meta, despite the fact that you were a top notch contributor.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: The comments weren't deleted, but they are posted on a deleted answer.

Comment: @Michael: Only those elected for moderator. :-)

Comment: @Asaf, I'm glad that you have written, "I am sorry to see Bill going," as I find it a great improvement on the " I was happy to see you leave, Bill" comment that you left at the *Should the old “losing Bill D.” thread be undeleted and re-locked?* thread.

Comment: @Gerry: I am not happy about his leaving, but I am happy that he is no longer a moderator.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I vote on Arturo.

Comment: I guess a lot of this went under my radar, though I did notice a bit of niggle - so I just wanted to record the impression of a user who visits the site regularly. Unfortunately there are human incompatibilities in this world - I think what I originally wrote recognised that - I know it wasn't really an answer. On the whole we need moderators who can contain such situations - not ones who are active participants. And on the whole I don't notice the moderators much, which I reckon means that they are doing a pretty good job most of the time.

Comment: @t.b. Thanks for your comment.  I hope you return to Math Stack Exchange soon.

Comment: @t.b. I miss your presence on Math.SE